are constrained alias templates allowed?
Checked the three major compilers, they all allow putting constraints on alias templates, for example:
template<class T, std::constructible_from<T> V>
using var_t = std::variant<T, V>;

template<class T, class...Args>
requires(std::constructible_from<T, Args...>)
using tup_t = std::tuple<T, Args...>;

But then cppreference has this to say:
Syntax
Alias declarations are declarations with the following syntax:

using identifier attr ﻿(optional) = type-id ;   (1)

template < template-parameter-list >
using identifier attr ﻿(optional) = type-id ;    (2)    

Is cpprefrence wrong and constraints are allowed?

How exactly is it wrong? Did you follow the link next to template-parameter-list to see what is and isn't allowed in a template parameter list? Constraints are covered there.

@StoryTeller - Unslander Monica how does template-parameter-list allow requires clause?

Why do you ask about constraints in general then?

@StoryTeller - Unslander Monica -- being half wrong is wrong isn't it?

Lots of ways take one towards being wrong. It happens when generalising too much as well. I guess you and cppref just need to meet half way.

There's a 3rd part to that definition in cppreference with the requires clause which is correctly marked C++20. In order to get detailed result from that page, you need set the "standard revision" to "diff" at the top of the page. I guess it is set to an old revision in your browser. Same references to cppreference can be perceived differently by different people. I guess "standard revision" is stored in the cookie.

Red.Wave -- good find

The cppreference is very good, but not always actual.
Yes, requires-clause is allowed in alias template that is a particular case of template-declaration. See temp.alias.
template-declaration:
    template-head declaration
    template-head concept-definition    

template-head:
    template < template-parameter-list > requires-clause[opt]


tnx, I suspected that compilers were right and cppreference was wrong
